# compare 2 arrays and get value that is closest to 0 in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 Arrays `$A` `$B` and `$C` that i want to compare to array `$D`, My result should be within array `$D`

```
$A = array(1,3,4,5,6); //for this i want 2

$B = array(-1,3,4,5,6); //for this i want 1

$C = array(1,2,3,4,5,6); //for this i want 7

and

$D = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

I have tried

```
$result = array_diff($D,$A);

echo $result[1];
```

but does not work in some scenario like `$C`

How do i compare the two arrays and get positive value that is closest to zero in php

Comment: Compare 2 arrays, but in the code you have 3 arrays, why?

Comment: editing, the result should be within the 3rd array

Comment: Your criteria is unclear. It seems to me like you're looking for the lowest positive number in `$C` that isn't present in the array that's matched against it? Also, can you please include your effort to solve this?

Comment: @El_Vanja i have edited my question thanks

Comment: If you say you want to compare to `$D`, why does your example do `$result = array_diff($A,$B);` where `$D` isn't involved?

Comment: So you want to find first missing positive number?

Comment: Yes nice_dev missing positive value, Thanks for understanding my question @nice_dev

Comment: What should be returned in case there is no difference?

Comment: return nothing if there is no difference @El_Vanja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reset` to fetch the first element of the difference, like below:

```
$result = array_diff($D,$C);
if(empty($result)){
    echo max($C) + 1; // or print nothing
}else{
    echo reset($result);
}
```

However, a the *key* point here is that `$D = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` has to be in a *sorted ascending manner* always or the script will break.

---

You can do this without using an extra `$D` in place by sorting the array and just looping through it keeping a pointer for comparison(If you do not wish to modify the array in place, make a new copy and sort it)

```
sort($C);
$curr = 1;
foreach($C as $key => $val){
    if($val <= 0 || $key > 0 && $C[$key] == $C[$key-1]) continue;
    if($curr != $val) break;
    $curr++;
}

echo $curr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have started well, you just need one extra function:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

```
$A = array(1,3,4,5,6); //for this i want 2

$B = array(-1,3,4,5,6); //for this i want 1

$C = array(1,2,3,4,5,6); //for this i want 7



$D = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$result = array_diff($D,$B);

//print_r($result);

echo reset($result);
```